# What is the value of char in this function?

Tags: c++

**UPDATE:**

While reading the answers, I felt that my question was not clear enough and I apologize for that.

The confusing thing for me is that in the first call for "disp_binary(sb.ch[1]);"  the value of the "u" inside the function will be 15 (that will make it always TRUE in the if condition because it is a non-zero value) and "t" will always be true inside the loop because (t>0) yet the output is:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

where did these zeros come from? shouldn't the output be:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

because both "u" and "t" will always be true in this call?

By the way, the output of the entire program is:

```
Original bytes:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
Exchanged bytes: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

I was learning about unions in C++ from a book and I encountered an example that I couldn't understand.

I understand the basic idea of unions, the thing that I didn't get in the example (see the example below) is the "void disp_binary(unsigned u)" function, more specifically what is the value of "u" that is being passed to the function? isn't it 15 for sb.ch[1] and 0 for sb.ch[0]? because I am very confused about why we are using "u" in the condition in the if statement?

This is the example:

```
// Use a union to exchange the bytes within a short integer.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void disp_binary(unsigned u);

union swap_bytes {
short int num;
char ch[2];
};

int main()
{
swap_bytes sb;
char temp;

sb.num = 15;  // binary: 0000 0000 0000 1111


 cout << "Original bytes:  ";
 disp_binary(sb.ch[1]);
 cout << "  ";
 disp_binary(sb.ch[0]);
 cout << "\n\n";


// exchange the bytes
temp = sb.ch[0];
sb.ch[0] = sb.ch[1];
sb.ch[1] = temp;

 cout << "Exchanged bytes: ";
 disp_binary(sb.ch[1]);
 cout << "  ";
 disp_binary(sb.ch[0]);
 cout << "\n\n";

 return 0;
 }

// Display the bits within a byte.
void disp_binary(unsigned u)
{
register int t;

for(t=128; t>0; t=t/2)
if(u & t) cout << "1 ";
else cout << "0 ";
}
```

Comment: Answered to the edit of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gray area according to C++ standard, that one can gain value of union's field after writing to another field. 
Technically reading from  a field of union that never was initialized and is an UB. And fields of union are *different* objects. Due historical reasons most of compilers allow type punning by union,  even while it's an UB by definition in C++ standard. It's recommended to avoid it if possible. One problem that arises here is that one field is short, while other is two bytes, some platforms wouldn't be able to  address separate bytes in memory where short was written. Result  might be dependent of endiannes of system, though GCC, for example, changes order of bytes to  allow same result on both little-endian and  big-endian platforms (tada, you can't test endianness of system by union).

In regard to your function  in question

```
void disp_binary(unsigned u)
{
   register int t;

    for(t=128; t>0; t=t/2)
      if(u & t) 
          cout << "1 ";
      else
          cout << "0 ";
}
```

& isn't a logical (boolean) operation, it's a binary (bitwise) operation. Let u be equal to 15 and t be equal to 8, the result of operation would be

00001111 & 00001000 = 00001000.

THAT value will be casted to a boolean value.

In fact, keyword `register` doesn't have any meaning anymore, and you can simplify your code, getting rid of the forked if() by a cast.

```
   void disp_binary(unsigned u)
   { 
        for(unsigned t = 128; t>0; t=t>>1)
        {
           std::cout << int(bool(u & t)) << " ";
        }
    }
```

Instead of this one may use std::bitset class of C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

I never see `sb.ch` being assigned anywhere, how are you sure that its 15 or 0? Its garbage since you didn't initialize it anywhere. where as `sb.num` has been assigned but never used.

The parameter to the function is `unsigned` i.e `unsigned int` and you keep passing a character to it which will be changed to and integer representation of the value. E.g: character '0' will be represented as 48 in the parameter and binary for '0' would be 110000 which should have been 000000 in this case.

Comment: the sb.num is assigned - that is why he is sure it is 15. otherwise you're right unsigned u means unsigned int u thus occupying all 16 bits in the union

Comment: @RomanAnanyev I already said "sb.num has been assigned but never used", he is passing sb.ch[i] to the function which make it unsure what would be the value when the function receives it, since he never initialized it.

Comment: Small correction: *"It's garbage"* is a bit inaccurate, the standard calls it *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 0):

The `unsinged u` actually mean `unsigned int u` and thus the function `disp_binary(sb.ch[0])` receives the char implicity converted to unsigned int.

And yes, you're right:
In case of `disp_binary(sb.ch[0])` (before swapping) it is 0.
In case of `disp_binary(sb.ch[1])` (before swapping) it is 15.

Comment: *" In case of `disp_binary(sb.ch[0])` it is 0"* - That is in no way guaranteed - as `sb.ch` has never been initialized reading from it is *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 0):

A Union is a structure that defines variables, which share the same space in memory. So sb.ch **is** automatically assigned, when assigning sb.num.
sb.ch[0] is the first 8 bits and sb.ch[1] are the last 8 bits.
So yes, sb.ch[0] would be 0 and sb.ch[1] would be 1.

the if(u & t) returns true if the bitwise and returns anything other than 0

Comment: that's one possible (widely expected) outcome, it's not a defined behavior. Question got tag C++, not C (ANSI C for punning to be valid)

Comment: it is at least supported in gcc